# Elasticsearch script query cosine similarity using dense_vector gives "class_cast_exception" Error

Tags: python, elasticsearch, cosine-similarity

I'm using Elasticsearch version 7.9.0 when I'm performing this query:

```
curl -XGET 'https:somehost:9200/index_name/_search' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "script_score": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "script": {
                "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, \u0027title_embed\u0027) + 1.0",
                "params": {
                    "query_vector": [-0.19277021288871765, 0.10494251549243927,.......]}
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Note: the `query_vector` is a Bert-generated 768 dimensions vector.
Note: `\u0027` is Unicode for a single quote.

I'm getting this error in response:

```
    "cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, 'title_embed') + 1.0","                   
                   ^---- HERE"],"script":"cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, 'title_embed') + 
1.0","lang":"painless","position":{"offset":38,"start":0,"end":58},"caused_by":
{"type":"class_cast_exception","reason":"class 
org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues$Doubles cannot be cast to class 
org.elasticsearch.xpack.vectors.query.VectorScriptDocValues$DenseVectorScriptDocValues 
(org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues$Doubles is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; 
org.elasticsearch.xpack.vectors.query.VectorScriptDocValues$DenseVectorScriptDocValues is in 
unnamed module of loader java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader @715fb77)"}}}]},"status":400}
```

Although the data type of the `title_embed` in the index mapping is Elasticsearch's `dense_vector` type, the error says it is a double I don't know why?

Here is the mapping:

```
"mappings": {
    "properties": {
        "description": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                }
            }
        },
        "domain": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                }
            }
        },
        "link": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                }
            }
        },
        "pub_date": {
            "type": "date"
        },
        "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                }
            }
        },
        "title_embed": {
            "type": "dense_vector",
            "dims": 768
        },
        "description_embed": {
            "type": "dense_vector",
            "dims": 768
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to perform this query using python I receive the same error:

```
status_code, error_message, additional_info
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', "class_cast_exception: class org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues$Doubles cannot be cast to class org.elasticsearch.xpack.vectors.query.VectorScriptDocValues$DenseVectorScriptDocValues (org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues$Doubles is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; org.elasticsearch.xpack.vectors.query.VectorScriptDocValues$DenseVectorScriptDocValues is in unnamed module of loader java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader @6d91790b)")
```

Comment: try the 2nd parameter to the cosineSimilarity() function to be doc['title_embed'] instead of just 'title_embed'

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible, check if the number of variables is equal to the number of dimensions in the mapping, i.e.

`dims:768`

Is the number of values in the "query_vector" equals to 768?

I suggest to check the mapping again to see if the mapping is good by running the following command:

```
GET index_name/_mapping
```

Also, you might have missed a value in the "query_vector" when passing it.

I did a test locally with however, 3 dimensions for the vector.

The mapping for title_embed was 3, with type as "dense_vector".

I ingested some data in my mapping as follows:

```
POST /index_name/_doc
{
  "title_embed": [10.01,15,15]
}
```

I tried to replicate your query with lower vector dimensions as mentioned above:

```
{
"size": 10,
    "query": {
        "script_score": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "script": {
                "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector,'title_embed') + 1.0",
                "params": {
                    "query_vector": [-0.19277021288871765, 0.10494251549243927,12.202022]
                
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: as Tom Elias mentioned, running the doc['title_embed'] will work but is deprecated in version 7.9.0 .

A small suggestion would be if it is possible to try with lower dimensions by reducing the vector dimensions when ingesting data in your index alongside with the mapping. If the number of dimensions are 5, then check if in the mapping the "dim" value is 5, when ingesting data also to your index and in the "query_vector"

```
"query_vector": [12,-1020.02000,10,-5.0000,2]
```

If this doesn't work,I think maybe there is an internal limit for the number of dimensions being allowed.

Helpful links:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/query-dsl-script-score-query.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dense-vector.html

Comment: Is it possible to run this query iteratively? By retrieving the query vector from another index?

Comment: I think it is not possible. Based on  this link:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest-apis.html

I thought of using an ingest pipeline to retrieve the data from another index but it is not possible to run it against a query based on my understanding. I am sorry, if I find any solution I will update the comment. Thank you.

Comment: @CharlesVanDamme you can code this on the application side, but not in one request itself. You'll never be able to do a relation between 2 indices directly into Elasticsearch.

Comment: @Jaycreation what if I define the second index as another type of document in the first index?

Comment: If you do so it will be the same index. The only not ways to do something like this is to use a nested or parent child. nested can be a good answer, but parent child rarely are.  but you will still not be able to do things iteratively. And most of the time when we try to do so in elastic we have misunderstood something of did an error in designing the app